# Is it possible to make multiple monitors (with glasses) in a way that each of the glasses would be able to see their specific monitor but not others?

Tags: optics, polarization, glass

So i was interested if i could make A B C monitors lets say and ive a b c glasses for all of them. My question was that is it physicly possible to make 3 same screens in a way that when i put on a glass it will be able to see only A monitor screen and b glasses only B monitor and c only C monitor.for example if i ise a glasses id be able to see only A screen and when i will look to the B and C screen it should show nothing unless im gonna use their specific glasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only consider polarization of light, I cannot see a way how this could be achieved for more than two displays – for each display there is only one angle at which no light is (theoretically) transmitted. If there are more than two pairs of glasses and displays, the third one will necessarily transmit some light.

However with some sort of active synchronization between the displays and the glasses at a high frequency it could be done for a higher number of displays $n$: each display $D_k$ ($k \in \left\{1, \ldots, n\right\})$ only outputs light in a short time interval in a round-robin fashion, during which the corresponding glasses $G_k$ also allow light transmission. This could be achieved with polarization or even mechanical shutters.

Of course, without any glasses you would still be able to see everything.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the solution by Martin Baláž:

Filter glass that allows only narrow-bands (i.e. colours) would enable the wearer to see only the image in the corresponding colour. The screen would need to represent the images by producing them in that wavelength.

Qualification:

Many screens have only three primary colour-generating elements, the apparent range of colours (and shades) being a mixture of light at different amplitudes at these wavelengths which the human eye and nervous system interpret as different - but are really just a mixture. To feed multiple distinct images to different viewers of number greater than three, a more complex screen with a greater number of colour-generating elements would be needed.

Comment: The OP's application only needs 3 colours per monitor. But monitors with 6 colours (2 different sets of RGB) have been used for 3D monitors, see the end section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichroic_filter

Comment: That's even better @PM2Ring With a nine-colour screen, the three people's brains could be fooled into thinking the full range of colours were present as if not through any filter. Neat idea.